# SymPy does not evaluate Latex2SymPy conversion for sin(-x) or sin(pi)

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

I have been using Latex2SymPy for a while successfully to handle all sorts of LaTeX inputs, but I have been running into troubles with a few functions. For instance:

```
from latex2sympy.process_latex import process_sympy
from sympy import *

inputLatex = '\\sin{-x}\\sin{-x}'
trigsimp(process_sympy(inputLatex))
```

sin(x)**2

That works great: trigsimp handled the simplification well. Now, if I try:

```
inputLatex = '\\sin{-x}'
trigsimp(process_sympy(inputLatex))
```

sin(-x)

Even though this is obviously correct, I expected trigsimp() to give me -sin(x) as an answer. In fact, if I run trigsimp straight from a sympy expression:

```
trigsimp(sin(-x))
```

-sin(x)

This is what I expect. Even running sin(-x) without the trigsimp() command returns me -sin(x). I checked the object type of my process_sympy('\\sin{-x}') call, and it is 'sin'.

I thought this might be something related with the way x is transformed into a Symbol type, but I then tried putting pi in the sin function.

```
inputLatex = '\\sin{\\pi}'
trigsimp(process_sympy(inputLatex))
```

sin(pi)

If I run straight sin(pi), I get 0 as an answer, with or without trigsimp().

Can any of you shed a light on this?

Comment: Did you try without the backslahes on sin? I have a feeling that \\sin is not being recognised as the sine function, but rather as a new symbol called sin. You can replicate this behaviour by running e.g. test = sympy.symbols('sin'); test(3); test(-3); sympy.trigsimp(test(-3))

Comment: I checked the object using type(). Latex2Sympy handles it correctly, converting LaTeX to Sympy format, and recognizing the sine function correctly(type 'sin'). It just doesn't evaluate that.

As for the backslashes, I need them, since it is a LaTeX format.

I have also tried other simplification functions, like fu(), exptrigsimp(), and the same problem happens.

Comment: hi I am unable to run above code, can you guide which python version you are using and how you have set up latex2sympy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is probably too late, you can solve that issue by calling the `doit()` method in the `sympy` expression obtained from `process_sympy(inputLatex)`.

When calling to `process_sympy`, it generates an [unevaluated sympy expression](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html), not a string. This expression cannot be evaluated just by calling `sympify`, since it has an attribute telling not to evaluate it.

You solved the problem by converting that expression to a string and then sympifying it, but a more direct way of doing it is just by using the `doit()` method in the expression:

```
inputLatex = '\\sin{-x}'
expr = process_sympy(inputLatex)
trigsimp(expr.doit())
```

would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved the whole mystery yet, but I found a dirty workaround, which is to use sympify(). So if anyone else faces the same issue, here is what I did to get it to work:

```
inputLatex = '\\sin{-x}'
sympify(str(process_sympy(inputLatex)))
```

The answer now is -sin(x), what I wanted.

As for the sin(pi) thing, the issue is that process_sympy() cannot distinguish the pi as a symbol from pi as a number. I did the test here, and type(process_sympy('\pi')) returns Symbol type, and not a number. The same solution applies here.